# Contour plot data extraction and replacing z slices with user defined function

Tags: plotting, graphics, data, data-structures

Let's say we have a contour plot of the following,

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}, 
ContourLabels -> True]
```

that gives,

[image]

we can extract the line objects and points associated with those lines as

```
Cases[Normal@%, Line[pts_] -> pts, Infinity]

ListLinePlot@%
```

which looks like in the following,

[image]

so, is there any way I can replace the line points, which are infact z slices with a user-defined function Sin[z]? so it will be Sin[-1.5],Sin[-1] and so on

and plot the contour plot again.

so extraction of data from the contour plot and changing it with a user-defined function

Comment: Is `z` the contourvalue?

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann yes!

Comment: Just to be clear, are you trying to rescale the contours lines?
So rather than the contour lines indicating points where the amplitude z = 1.5 for example, you prefer it to instead show points where the amplitude is Sin[1.5]?

Comment: @alex Yes, rescaling z=1.5 with a function Sin[z] or Sin[1.5], so kind of replacing as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
plot = ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi} ]
```

detect contourlines and values

```
list = Cases[Normal@plot, Tooltip[{__, a__Line }, b_] :> {b, a  },Infinity];
```

create new points `Sin[conourvalue]`

```
p3D = Flatten[
Table[Map[Join[#, {Sin[list[[i, 1]]]}] &, list[[i, 2]][[1 ]]], {i,Length[list]}] , 1] 
ListPlot3D[p3D, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}]
```

[image]

Comment: can we plot p3D in 2D contourplot rather than in Graphics3D?

Comment: @a019 I modified my answer

Answer (score 2):

Manipulating the list as shown by @Ulrich is what one would do to simply rescale.

For the sake of completion, I'm also adding the option in case you wanted to know the contour points for a specified function. You can achieve this using `ContourPlot3D`:

```
ContourPlot3D[
 Cos[x] + Cos[y] == Sin[z], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

You of course recover your default answers by leaving the equation unspecified:

```
ContourPlot3D[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}, {z, -2, 2}, 
 Contours -> 11]
```

[image]

Best of luck.